# query_posts that have custom taxonomy and limiting what shows based on the taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, taxonomy

I have a custom post type, `technologies`, that has a custom taxonomy defined for it, `importance`.  The idea is that a technology that has any significance will get `importance` tagged on it (`featured` is what I'm testing).

Here's my query with a check for the taxonomy:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => $num,
'offset'           => 0,
'orderby'          => 'post_date',
'order'            => 'DESC',
'post_type'        => 'technologies',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'paged'            => $paged,
'suppress_filters' => true ); 

query_posts($args);

if (has_term('featured','importance')) {
// do nothing since these are feeding in somewhere else
} else {
// feed in stuff
}
```

`$num` is defined as `10` as of right now.  The else part of the if statement has a lot of code feeding in posts (which it is doing correctly) but is feeding in `technologies` that are tagged with `featured` in the `importance` taxonomy.

Am I using the correct function to check for taxonomies?

Comment: In which template is this. And never ever use `query_posts`, it does break page functionalities and the main query. You might not even need a custom query here depending on template

Comment: It is actually a shortcode that I'm using on a normal page.  If I don't want query_posts, what do I want?  new WP_Query?

Comment: Correct yes. There is also a few other small issues in you code.

Comment: Well issues aside, what's the correct way to check for my custom taxonomy?

Comment: I will post an answer soon on what I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lot of issues here;

- Never ever use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query and page functionalities.
- You are breaking and nullifying the main query even before `query_posts` can have a change to do it in this line `$wp_query= null`
- As this is a shortcode (taken from your comments) and with this line, `'posts_per_page'   => $num,`, I believe that you are using `extract()`. You should never use `extract()` as it is almost un-debuggable, unreliable and fails silently. For this reason it was removed from core functions`
- The correct value to `orderby` to sort by post date is `date`, not `post_date`. This is the default, so you can just omit this as you are not modifying it through an attribute. This also goes for `offset` and `order`
- You need to use a [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) to get posts from a specific term

Here is a small example you can work from. (*Please note, you should sanitize and validate all user inputs. I have not done any of that*).

```
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', function ( $atts )
{
    $attributes = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'numberposts' => 10, // Default amount of posts to show
            'post_type'   => 'technologies', // Default post type
            'taxonomy'    => 'importance', // Default taxonomy
            'terms'       => 'featured' // Default term to exclude
        ],
        $atts, 
        'my_shortcode' 
    );

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = [
        'posts_per_page'   => $attributes['numberposts'],
        'post_type'        => $attributes['post_type'],
        'tax_query'        => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => $attributes['taxonomy'],
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $attributes['terms'],
                'operator' => 'NOT IN' // This will exclude all posts with terms set in 'terms'
            ]
        ],
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'paged'            => $paged,
        'suppress_filters' => true
    ];
    $q = new WP_Query( $args );

    $output = '';
    if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
            $q->the_post();

            $output .= apply_filters( 'the_title', get_the_title() );

        }
        $output .= get_next_posts_links( 'Next', $q->max_num_pages );
        $output .= get_previous_posts_links( 'Previous' );
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    return $output;
});
```

You can just call it as `[my_shortcode]` if you don't need to change the defaults

### FINAL NOTES

- I assumed that you would want to exclude the `featured` term, so I have written the `tax_query` around that.
- You will need PHP5.4+ as the code uses the new short array syntax (`[]`). If you have an older version, just change to the old array syntax (`array()`). Just be sure then you have at least PHP 5.3 to support the closure used

Comment: My pleasure. Glad it worked out. Enjoy :-)